# Auto-generate person_id and student_id for SINGLE_TABLE inheritance model

Tags: java, jpa, persistence, eclipselink, auto-generate

I have two entities `person` and `Student`, the student entity extends person and has its own identifier `studentNumber`. When creating a new student, i want to auto-generate both identification numbers.

The following snippet fails with: person_id being `NULL`

```
@RooEntity(identifierColumn = "personID", inheritanceType = "SINGLE_TABLE")
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "TYPE", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING, length = 20)
@DiscriminatorValue("P")
public class Person {
}
```

The student Entity

```
@RooEntity
@DiscriminatorValue("S")
public class Student extends Person {


    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "studentNumber") 
    private long studentNumber;
}
```

Here is where i create a new student and the student number is generated but personid is not?

```
    private Student student;

    /**
     * @method Create a new student using our persistence model---Not Null variables
     */

    public void CreateNewStudent(String firstName, String lastName, String telephone, Date birthday, GenderType gender){


        student = new Student();
        //set our variables and persist
        student.setFirstName(firstName);
        student.setLastName(lastName);
        student.setTelephone(telephone);
        student.setBirthDay(birthday);
        student.setGender(gender);

        student.persist();
    }
}
```

is there any way i can create both studentNumber and personID when a student is created?

Comment: I question this design. Why have primary key on both the parent and derived table, when using single table inheritance? Please show your schema.

Comment: the student number isn't really to identify a particular record, its a number representing the students identification, person id should be the only primary key

Comment: Ah ok that makes sense, see my answer below for one way to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your follow-up comments what you want is to have a primary key identifier for `Person`, and a unique identifier for `Student`. Note that with your current setup, only one of the keys can be auto generated (many DBMSes only allow one column per table to be auto incremented). So I would recommend that you first define your primary key column for `Person`:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="person")
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="TYPE", discriminatorType=DiscriminatorType.STRING,length=20)
@DiscriminatorValue("P")
public class Person {
    @Basic
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="personId")
    private Long id;
}
```

Note that in your DB you will want to have the personId column as the auto-increment. Then define a separate generated value annotation for your student numbers. The example I show below uses a table generator but you can do whatever you want:

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("S")
public class Student extends Person {
   @Basic
   @TableGenerator(name="ID_GEN", table="identifier_table", pkColumnName="seq_name",
        valueColumnName="seq_count", pkColumnValue="student_seq")
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE, generator = "ID_GEN")
   @Column(name = "studentNumber")
   private Long studentNumber;
}
```

Heres the DDL for the table you will need to support sequence number generation for Students, given the example above:

```
create table identifier_table (
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  seq_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  seq_count INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
);
```

And you would initially populate it with:

```
insert into identifier_table (seq_name, seq_count) VALUES ('student_seq', 0);
```

Of course, the simpler solution would be to declare your student identifier's as String, then you could just do the following, much easier setup:

```
public class Student extends Person {
    @Basic
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "studentId")
    private String studentIdentifier;
}
```

And before saving each record, set the student ID with the UUID class:

```
aStudent.setStudentIdentifier(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: For the simpler solution where the student identifier is created with UUID.randUUID(), is this really unique? is there a way i can start at a random number ex.10000 and then for each new student added to the person table, increment by 1?

Comment: You can read more about UUID's on the Oracle javadoc page - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html. But suffice to say, its pretty **damn** unique. Globally.

Comment: one last thing, if i change my createNewStudent() method to create not a person but a student entity, shouldn't my database with the changes you mentioned to the student entity generate an id for person?

Comment: Yes, it will as long as you define the `personId` column to be auto increment in the database. One last thing I forgot to mention. Do not set your studentId database field to be NOT NULL, since conceptually you will be storing other records in the table that may *not* be students. And you do not want to have to set the studentId column in that case.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can only have one GenerateValue currently.  If you want two, you either need to not use inheritance, i.e. Person has a 1-1 to StudentInfo, or you could assign the other id in an event or from your app.  There is an API on the EclipseLink Session to get a new generated id.

Comment: could you please post a link to the API on EclipseLink Session generating an ID.

Comment: http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/api/2.3/org/eclipse/persistence/sessions/Session.html#getNextSequenceNumberValue%28java.lang.Class%29